# Speed up playback rate of online videos in web browser on Debian Linux

Tags: debian, video, vlc

Windows and Mac users have Enounce MySpeed to assist with increasing playback speed of online videos. What options do I have for increasing playback rate of online videos in Google Chrome on Debian (Squeeze)?

Downloading videos and watching locally won't work; I don't have the time/motivation to do so on a regular basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy-paste the URL (e.g. from YouTube) into VLC (the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>).

Then you can adjust the speed in VLC with *Playback→Speed*
or click on the `1.00x` icon at the bottom right, then you get a nice slider. The keyboard shortcuts are <kbd>-</kbd> for slower and <kbd>+</kbd> for faster (the latter one is not working on my system for some reason).

Comment: Accepting this as the answer...will space you all the gory details, but eventually got VLC installed and working to play YouTube videos. By default, the Debian Squeeze repository includes VLC 1.1.3...I eventually got the VLC 2.0.3 backports version working, but even this required a youtube.lua configuration file update from the nightly build. A pain in the butt, for sure, but it works. : o ) Thank you.